# Https Repository confiuration in maven for jira Development Environment

Tags: maven, https, maven-2, jira

can any one please tell me how to configure maven to download jar's from https repository (eg: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/). we are able to download jar's from http repositories  but not from https repositories

Comment: What is the error you've faced?

Comment: Error:  Unable to get resource 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:pom:1.2' from repository atlassian-public (https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public): Error transferring file: m2proxy.atlassian.com

Comment: Please provide your `settings.xml` and/or `pom.xml` which are related to the `<repositories>` configuration.

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk, sorry, i don't have setting.xml right now, i will post sometime later today. i can summerize the contents in setting.xml i have mentioned proxy setting and a repository which ponits to https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/. Proxy is working for http sites like "repo.maven" site, but it is not working for https sites

Comment: As mentioning https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Atlassian+Maven+Repositories the Atlassin repo is https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public instead.

Comment: even after changing to " maven.atlassian.com/repository/public", it is not working. getting same error

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved!!.. i used an alternative "HTTP" repository which is : http://repository.atlassian.com/maven2/ and mentioned it as both "repository" and "pluginRepository" in settings.xml.

Thanks for all your reply

Comment: You can accepts and promote my answer if it answers your question and not create your answer (add a comment) :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a minute ago and it works fine

1)  Add the following repository in your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
      <id>https-atlassian</id>
      <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

2)  Add dependency. I have added

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>andromda</groupId>
   <artifactId>andromda-java</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

3)  Downloaded without problems during maven install

```
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/andromda/andromda-j
ava/2.1.5/andromda-java-2.1.5.pom
Downloaded: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/andromda/andromda-ja
va/2.1.5/andromda-java-2.1.5.pom (155 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/andromda/andromda-j
ava/2.1.5/andromda-java-2.1.5.jar
Downloaded: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/andromda/andromda-ja
va/2.1.5/andromda-java-2.1.5.jar (2 KB at 3.0 KB/sec)
```